# Monitoring the state of daemon

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have a C++ Qt application which works with daemon (spnav) - receives X11 messages from it. Is it possible to receive some kind of notification, if daemon crashes? I know that I can create loop in separate thread, but I must operate only with one thread. Does Linux (or X11, or someone else) send any broadcasts when application crashes?

Comment: Check [Linux Signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal).

Comment: Parent process can get a notification.
You might also want to use some tool to monitor and restart you service http://superuser.com/questions/683325/linux-to-monitor-a-service-and-restart-if-stopped

Comment: @y_ug thanks a lot! Starting daemon from my process is really good idea!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @y_ug, I have found a solution - start the daemon process as a child of my program.